# how to write using the rte_write function in autosar for structure members in CAN frame

Tags: autosar

In autosar, RTE generation one of our software component like Rte_Write API with structure arguments how to write in CAN frame individually.

Comment: Hi. Welcome. Please see this post to edit a question for the community to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

RTE_Write API is dedicated to Software level. For Network transportation you have to define DataMapping and optionally Transformer for the way data are split/collapsed.